# Rethrowing exception in Task doesn't make the Task to go to faulted state

Tags: c#, multithreading, task, thread-abort

Consider following scenario

```
 var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
        var startNew = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            var currentThread = Thread.CurrentThread;
            try
            {
                using (cancellationTokenSource.Token.Register(currentThread.Abort))
                    new AutoResetEvent(false).WaitOne(Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan);
            }
            catch (ThreadAbortException abortException)
            {
                throw new TimeoutException("Operation timeouted", abortException);
            }
        }, cancellationTokenSource.Token, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, TaskScheduler.Current);
        startNew.ContinueWith(val => Console.WriteLine("Cancellation handled"), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnCanceled);
        startNew.ContinueWith(val => Console.WriteLine("Fault handled"), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
        startNew.ContinueWith(val => Console.WriteLine("Ran to completion handled"), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);
```

Putting aside all the discussion that aborting threads is evil, why does this code doesn't make the task to go to Faulted state? However removing catch block or calling

```
Thread.ResetAbort()
```

seems to do the trick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is about how thread abort works:

```
try {
    try {
        try {
            Thread.CurrentThread.Abort();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            Console.WriteLine(e.GetType());
            throw new Exception();
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        Console.WriteLine(e.GetType());
    }
} catch(Exception e) {
    Console.WriteLine(e.GetType());
}
```

This code prints:

```
System.Threading.ThreadAbortException
System.Exception
System.Threading.ThreadAbortException
```

So, when your custom exception would be handled, `ThreadAbortException` whould be re-thrown.

> `ThreadAbortException` is a special exception that can be caught by application code, but is re-thrown at the end of the `catch` block unless `ResetAbort` is called. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty8d3wta.aspx)

Now let us look to some [source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/a.html#221a67fe0126b663):

```
/// <summary>
/// Executes the task. This method will only be called once, and handles bookeeping associated with
/// self-replicating tasks, in addition to performing necessary exception marshaling.
/// </summary>
private void Execute()
{
    if (IsSelfReplicatingRoot)
    {
        ExecuteSelfReplicating(this);
    }
    else
    {
        try
        {
            InnerInvoke();
        }
        catch (ThreadAbortException tae)
        {
            // Don't record the TAE or call FinishThreadAbortedTask for a child replica task --
            // it's already been done downstream.
            if (!IsChildReplica)
            {
                // Record this exception in the task's exception list
                HandleException(tae);

                // This is a ThreadAbortException and it will be rethrown from this catch clause, causing us to 
                // skip the regular Finish codepath. In order not to leave the task unfinished, we now call 
                // FinishThreadAbortedTask here.
                FinishThreadAbortedTask(true, true);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exn)
        {
            // Record this exception in the task's exception list
            HandleException(exn);
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, there is special codepath for `ThreadAbortException` case to transit task to the faulted state. As you hide `ThreadAbortException` by `TimeoutException`, that special codepath are not taken. So when regular codepath handle exception by recording it in the task's exception list, `ThreadAbortException` would be re-thrown, which prevent correct task transition to the faulted state.