# Odd behavior: Catching ThreadAbortException and throwing different exception

Tags: c#, .net, exception, threadabortexception, thread-abort

As a result of investigating this question: [Rethrowing exception in Task doesn't make the Task to go to faulted state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31574378/rethrowing-exception-in-task-doesnt-make-the-task-to-go-to-faulted-state), I noticed some very odd behavior with the `ThreadAbortException` that I can't make sense of.

Now, I know that `ThreadAbortException` is a very special kind of exception to begin with. And the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadabortexception(v=vs.110).aspx) is pretty clear about that when it says:

> `ThreadAbortException` is a special exception that can be caught, but it will automatically be raised again at the end of the `catch` block.

**Scenario #1**: Documented behavior.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.Abort();
    }
    catch (Exception tae)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("caught exception: " + tae.GetType().Name);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("will never be reached");
}
```

As expected, the `ThreadAbortException` is rethrown automatically, resulting in the following output:

```
caught exception: ThreadAbortException
```

**Scenario #2**: Where it gets interesting is when I decide to throw a different exception in the `catch` block:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.Abort();
    }
    catch (Exception tae)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("caught exception: " + tae.GetType().Name);
        throw new ApplicationException(); // will ThreadAbortException take precedence?
    }
    Console.WriteLine("will never be reached");
}
```

In this case, I assumed that, despite the throwing of the `ApplicationException`, that the `ThreadAbortException` would be rethrown anyways to ensure that the documented behavior was preserved.  To my surprise, this is the output that resulted:

```
caught exception: ThreadAbortException

Unhandled Exception: System.ApplicationException: Error in the application.
   at ConsoleApplication1.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\projects\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs:line 193
```

Did the `ApplicationException` actually *replace* and *prevent* the `ThreadAbortException` from being thrown?!?

**Scenario #3**: And finally, to make matters more interesting, I wrap my existing exception handling with one more `try-catch` layer:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        try
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.Abort();
        }
        catch (Exception tae)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("caught exception: " + tae.GetType().Name);
            throw new ApplicationException();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception outerEx)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("caught outer exception: " + outerEx.GetType().Name);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("will never be reached");
}
```

Now I'm not too sure what to expect.  Which exception will be caught in the outer `catch` block?  Will it be `ApplicationException`?  And if so, does that mean that I'll be able to swallow the exception and actually manage to print out the `will never be reached` string after all?

This is the actual output:

```
caught exception: ThreadAbortException
caught outer exception: ApplicationException
```

From the above output, it looks like the outer `catch` block does actually catch an `ApplicationException`. But by the end of *that* `catch` block, the `ThreadAbortException` now all of a sudden reappears out of thin air and gets rethrown?

**Question(s)**: Can someone explain and reconcile scenarios #2 and #3?  How is it that in scenario #2, it looks as though the `ThreadAbortException` is, unexpectedly, replaced by a different exception?  Yet, in scenario #3, it looks like `ThreadAbortException` was still there all along? How is this happening? Is this behavior documented somewhere?

Comment: Even more interested in hooking into the `AppDomain.UnhandledException` event - it fires even if you handle it, as you would expect, but you don't get the default behavior otherwise.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/jdphenix/32a710ad5def12cf121c - Run this, in clearly demonstrates that `ThreadAbortException` continues to propogate. I don't have an explanation on why the default unhandled exception handler doesn't grab it.

Comment: @jdphenix: Now try commenting out the `try-catch` in your `HandleApplicationException(Action action)` method and see which exception is caught inside the `AppDomain.UnhandledException` event handler. Notice how, in this case, it feels like the `ThreadAbortException` did not propagate, and instead the `ApplicationException` propagates. Very odd.

Comment: so from what i read, in the scenario 2 the thread abort exception still there but as application exception came in front of it, thread abort gave a way and application exception became unhandled exception, but in the third case you handled the application exception but now the thread abort exception became unhandled. So always there will be only one unhandled exception.

Comment: @sstan Right - in that case though, a `ThreadAbortException` doesn't much matter then because you've got an unhandled normal exception that would crash the program anyhow

Comment: @jdphenix: You're right, of course.  And I'm certainly not trying to find a practical application to any of this. I'm just trying to wrap my head around how this works.

Comment: I figured that. Me too :)

Answer (score 1):

The behavior is implementation specific.

From [*Ecma-335 VI Annex E, Portability Considerations*](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-335.pdf?page=543):

> This clause gathers together information about areas where this Standard deliberately leaves leeway to implementations. This leeway is intended to allow compliant implementations to make choices that provide better performance or add value in other ways. But this leeway inherently makes programs non-portable.  ...

and further (emphasis mine):

> V I . E . 1 Uncontrollable Behavior
>
> The following aspects of program behavior are implementation dependent. >Many of these items
> will be familiar to programmers used to writing code designed for >portability (for example, the
> fact that the CLI does not impose a minimum size for heap or stack).
>
> 1. Size of heap and stack aren't required to have minimum sizes
>
> **Behavior relative to asynchronous exceptions (see System.Thread.Abort)**
>
> Globalization is not supported, so every implementation specifies its culture information  including such user-visible features as sort order for strings.
>
> Threads cannot be assumed to be either pre -emptively or non-pre-emptively scheduled. This decision is implementation specific.
>
> Locating assemblies is an implementation-specific mechanism.
>
> Security policy is an implemenation-specific mechanism.
>
> File names are implementation-specific.
>
> Timer resolution (granularity) is implementation -specific, although the unit is specified.